# How to resolve if statements in login forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I tap an RFID that is not registered to the database it won't display the msgbox. I use some conditional statement using else but it wont work either. I tried the not equal to operator but didn't work either

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    process1:
    Try

        rec = New ADODB.Recordset
        rec.Open("SELECT * from admin where rfid='" & TextBox4.Text & "'", con, 1, 2)

        Dim y As Integer
        y = 0

        While Not rec.EOF

            rec.MoveNext()
            y = y + 1

        End While

        If y = 1 Then
                Timer1.Stop()
                Me.Hide()
                MsgBox("VALID RFID! WELCOME ADMIN!")
                SystemForm.Show()
                TextBox4.Text = ""

            If y <> 1 Then

                Timer1.Stop()
                MsgBox("Invalid RFID NO.!")
                TextBox4.Text = ""

            End If

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Timer1.Stop()
        MsgBox("Invalid RFID NO.!")
        TextBox4.Text = ""
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: With this sample code, it looks like your `End If`'s are not in the right spot.  Try moving the second `End If` between the 2 If's.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work the same. Hahahha I tried that before it displays the "Invalid RFID" string before i tap the tag.

Comment: Paste this in TextBox4 and see what happens: `0'; drop table admin;--`. You can read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: If y = 1, it will never be *not* 1 inside that IF block.  If you are going to count records, use a query that counts it for you.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Nevermind dudes. I just removed my timer and moved the codes in my textbox with keydown event. Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you enable the timer within your code or did you set Enabled to True in the designer? What interval did you set for the timer? Sounds like the code posted above is running prior to you having the ability to populate the text box.

When I catch exceptions, I use the Message and StackTrace for error reporting. You might want to replace the MsgBox text in your exception handler so that it is more informative to you. I would be willing to bet that the MsgBox you are seeing is in fact from the Catch block.

Comment: Its disabled though.

Comment: I do not believe that the code block above would run if the timer had enabled=false.

Comment: Do you enable the timer within your code or did you set Enabled to True in the designer? What interval did you set for the timer? Sounds like the code posted above is running prior to you having the ability to populate the text box.

When I catch exceptions, I use the Message and StackTrace for error reporting. You might want to replace the MsgBox text in your exception handler so that it is more informative to you. I would be willing to bet that the MsgBox you are seeing is in fact from the Catch block.

Comment: Its false though in the timer properties. I really don't know why the code works in my program even if the timer is disabled.

Comment: It must being set to enabled somewhere. Put a breakpoint on the msgbox that appears within the catch block and run your code. Then, hover over the catch line and you’ll see an exception is being thrown

Comment: Nevermind dude. I just removed my timer and moved the codes in my textbox with keydown event. Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 1):

I think an `else` would be the best case for you. I've also moved some of the shared logic out of the conditional:

```
Timer1.Stop()

If y = 1 Then
    Me.Hide()
    MsgBox("VALID RFID! WELCOME ADMIN!")
    SystemForm.Show()
Else
    Timer1.Stop()
    MsgBox("Invalid RFID NO.!")
End If

TextBox4.Text = ""
```

There are a lot of other changes I'd make in the long run, too, including using `SELECT COUNT(rfid)` for your query which will always return a number, and actually moving away from `ADODB` in general, but the above should probably get what you are going for.

**Edit**

Here's a full alternative version that includes specific debug points. I was a long-term VB guy but I'll admit to being a bit rusty, so you might need to tweak a thing or two.

**Some very important things:**

1. I've removed the `try/catch`. I always recommend saving that until you have working code, it tends to hide tiny little bugs. When you are developing something, the exceptions are what tell you what is wrong in the first place and you really want to see those.
2. I'm using `MsgBox` to show strings when ideally you'd use the console, but I'm doing that because that's how your code was written.
3. **Most important**. Whatever the SQL is that gets kicked out, you must manually run that against your database **while the MsgBox is still open**. That is critical. Running it manually will tell you if you've got an syntax errors, or possibly type-cast issues. Running it with the MsgBox still open will (better) guarantee that you don't have a race-condition with other code that might be talking to the database. If running the SQL manually against your database doesn't produce what you expect, fix it or post the problem here for us to look at, including any errors. If running the SQL manually works but the code doesn't, check your connection object, maybe you're talking to a different database?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Timer1.Stop()

    ' First lets find out what is in the text box
    MsgBox("Searching for rfid: " & TextBox4.Text)

    ' Next, lets take a look at the SQL
    sql = "SELECT * from admin where rfid='" & TextBox4.Text & "'"
    MsgBox("Using SQL: " & sql)

    rec = New ADODB.Recordset
    rec.Open(sql, con, 1, 2)

    Dim y As Integer
    y = 0

    While Not rec.EOF
        rec.MoveNext()
        y = y + 1
    End While

    Timer1.Stop()

    If y = 1 Then
        Me.Hide()
        MsgBox("VALID RFID! WELCOME ADMIN!")
        SystemForm.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid RFID NO.!")
    End If

    TextBox4.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry bro didn't work too. Same results too with brian's suggestion up above. I cant get it seem to work. Whenever I click the menutoolstrip and login panel the msgbox Invalid RFID No.! shows up instantly

Comment: Didn't work either. I tried dim the sql to string but no effect. Is there anything wrong with the while not statement??

Comment: Can you post the exact SQL that is being run, the one from the MsgBox?

Comment: The connection module??

Comment: The connection string is inside a module file. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Nevermind dude. I just removed my timer and moved the codes in my textbox with keydown event. Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 1):

First, why use a development tool that is a decade old. Visual Studio 2019 Community is free for the download.

Get rid of the `Timer` altogether and just use a login button.

Let us move into the current decade and use `ADO.net` instead of `ADODB`.

Since I don't know what database you are using I gave an example using Sql Server. If the database is Access then you would have to change the Sql database objects to OleDb objects. Import one of the following at the top of your file.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

or

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Database objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error. You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection, and the command text and connection directly to the constructor of the command. Notice that they are both included in the same Using block.

Don't pull down data when all you need is count. Just ask for count. Never concatenate strings to build Sql queries. Always use parameters to avoid Sql injection.

I had to guess at the datatype of rfid. Check your database for the actual type and adjust the code accordingly.

`.ExecuteScalar` returns the first row, first column if the result set. In this case the record count.

Notice that the connection is not openned until just before the `.Execute...`. It is closed immediately after with the `End Using`. We don't start comparing the result and showing message boxes until after the connection is closed.

If you try this code and it doesn't work, please tell us what the error is and what line it occurs on.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Tick
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Count(*) Form admin Where rfid = @rfid;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@rfid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox4.Text)
        cn.Open()
        RetVal = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    If RetVal = 1 Then
        MsgBox("VALID RFID! WELCOME ADMIN!")
        SystemForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid RFID NO.!")
    End If
    TextBox4.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using a module though and the connection string is coded in there

Comment: In my college, we use really outdated program such as Sql and Visual Studio 2010. 
The devices and software used in my school is really old and its just a municipal college. I'm in the Philippines BTW

Comment: The code doesn't work sadly. I guess I'm just going to not add an else statement then

Comment: Nevermind! I just removed my timer and moved the codes in my textbox with keydown event. Thanks for your help anyways

Comment: @LameProgrammer99 What? You mean you run the code on every key press?